# Defining a pointer in a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I've create a structure Person and had these variables in it, then I added a new field named father and its type is pointer to a person.
I have to initialize the data of FJames as following: fname = Whatever, lname = Bond, age = 80, job = Farmer, father = NULL

Then initialize the data of James as following: fname = James, lname = Bond, age = 40, job = Actor, father = FJames

Then display all the data.
I'm getting an error " initializing struct Person * with an expression of incompatible type "Person"
What to do? :/
I don't even think I'm doing it right, please help!

```
/#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int age;
    char *fname;
    char *lname;
    char *job;
    struct Person *father;
}Person;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    Person James;
    Person FJames = {80,"Whatever","Bond","Painting",NULL};
    James.age = 40;
    James.fname = "James";
    James.lname = "Bond";
    James.job = "Engineering";
    James.father = FJames;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't declare `struct Person` actually.

You're declaring anonymous structure and typedef it to person. You then should use it as just `Person`, not `struct Person`.

```
struct Person {
    struct Person *father; // this will work
}
```

or if you want typedef

```
typedef struct s_Person {
    struct s_Person *father
} Person;
```

Comment: This. The first sentence of this answer is the short answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct {
    int age;
    char *fname;
    char *lname;
    char *job;
    struct Person *father; // << This is a pointer to a Person
} Person;


James.father = FJames;
```

`FJames` is not a `Person*`. He's a `Person`. You need to `malloc` him in order to get a `Person*`. Or take his address with `&`

This code has some other issues, but that's the one that's giving you the error in question.

Answer (score 0):

That last line should be

```
James.father = &FJames;
```

The `father` field is a pointer, but FJames is a `Person`. You can use `&` to get the address of `FJames`.

**Edit**

The struct definition should also be changed in addition to that, in one of the ways aragaer suggested, e.g.:

```
typedef struct s_Person {
    // ...
    struct s_Person *father;
} Person;
```

Comment: How can I print all the data in James?

Comment: Declaring `Person *father` inside the struct didn't work for me.

Comment: @aragaer you are right, I have corrected the answer. Too long not coding any C I guess...

Answer (score 0):

James.father = &FJames should be what you need.

There are other minor problems. These days initialising a char* from a string constant is frowned upon, because char* implies that the memory being pointed at can be altered.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Person {
    int age;
    char *fname;
    char *lname;
    char *job;
    struct Person *father;
} Person;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    Person James;
    Person FJames = {80,"Whatever","Bond","Painting",NULL};
    James.age = 40;
    James.fname = "James";
    James.lname = "Bond";
    James.job = "Engineering";
    James.father = &FJames;

    fprintf(stdout, "%d\t%s\t%s\t%s\tpops:\t%s\t%s\n", James.age, James.fname, James.lname, James.job, (James.father)->fname, (James.father)->lname);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Corrections:

1. You should correct your `typedef` so that it declares `Person`.
2. When setting `James.father` it should dereference `FJames` so that you are setting it to the value of the pointer to `FJames`.
3. Your `main()` function should return an `int`, so return `EXIT_SUCCESS` (defined in `stdlib.h`) to note that you exited properly.

Advice:

1. When dereferencing properties of `James.father`, use precedence and arrow notation to dereference its values.
2. If you are using `gcc`, compile with `-Wall` option to enable all compilation warnings. This will help note warnings that point where corrections are needed.